# Tweepy search_full_archive() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'label' and 'query'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy 3.10.0 to collect tweets containing specific keywords and hashtags for a single calendar day at a time. I recently upgraded from the standard Developer Account to the Premium Account to access the full archive. I know this changes the "search" function to "search_full_archive" and changes a couple other small syntax things. I thought I made the correct changes but I'm still getting this error. I've checked the Developer API reference.

```
consumer_key = '****'
consumer_secret = '****'
access_token = '****'
access_token_secret = '****'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

def get_tweets_withHashTags(query, startdate, enddate, count = 300):
    tweets_hlist= []
    tweets_list= []
    qt=str(query) 
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive, environment_name='FullArchive', q=qt, fromDate=startdate,toDate=enddate,count=300, tweet_mode='extended').pages(100):
      count = len(page)
      print( "Count of tweets in each page for  " + str(qt) + " : " +  str(count))
      for value in page:
        hashList = value._json["entities"]["hashtags"]
        flag = 0
        for tag in hashList:
            if qt.lower() in tag["text"].lower():
                flag = 1

        if flag==1:
          tweets_hlist.append(value._json)
        tweets_list.append(value._json)

    print("tweets_hash_"+ query +": " + str(len(tweets_hlist)))
    print("tweets_"+ query +": " + str(len(tweets_list)))
    
    with open("/Users/Victor/Documents/tweetCollection/data/"+startdate +"/" + "query1_hash_" + str(startdate)+ "_" + str(enddate) + "_" +query+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(tweets_hlist, outfile, indent = 2)

    with open("/Users/Victor/Documents/tweetCollection/data/"+startdate +"/"+"query1_Contains_" + str(startdate)+ "_" + str(enddate) + "_" +query+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(tweets_list, outfile, indent = 2)
    return len(tweets_list)

query = ["KeyWord1","KeyWord2","KeyWord3",etc.]

for value in query:
  get_tweets_withHashTags(value,"2020-04-21","2020-04-22")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the api's code https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/5b2dd086c2c5a08c3bf7be54400adfd823d19ea1/tweepy/api.py#L1144 api.search_full_archive has as arguments label (the environment name) and query. So changing

```
api.search_full_archive, environment_name='FullArchive', q=qt, fromDate=startdate,toDate=enddate,count=300, tweet_mode='extended'
```

to

```
api.search_full_archive, label='FullArchive', query=qt, fromDate=startdate,toDate=enddate
```

As for the tweet_mode='extended', it is not available for search_full_archive nor search_30_day. You can see how to access full text in https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1461

Comment: does that also works for the academic research account?

Comment: The search_full_archive uses a paid premium subscription, for the academic research account there is a search/all endpoint (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all). It appears it is not yet available on the Master branch of tweepy, you can try through the api-v2 branch: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/api-v2/tweepy/client.py, see search_all_tweets. 

You can also try through the twitter official github examples: https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Full-Archive-Search/full-archive-search.py .